How to implement static row numbers in MUI-X DataGrid?
I need to render the number of each row in the table. It should be static and should not change when sorting or filtering the columns in the table.
I tried to use getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows method of grid api but it does not work when sorting and filtering and row numbers are mixed with rows data.
I think the problem is that when I change the order of sorting or filtering in table column menu, the cell with the row number will not render again.
That’s what I’ve tried:
<DataGridPremium 
  columns=[{ 
    field: 'id',
    renderCell: (params) => params.api.getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows(params.id),
  }]
  
  rows={[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]}
/>


Are you using DataGrid Component or Table Component ?
DataGrid works fine for with this
`<DataGrid
columns=[{
field: 'id',
renderCell: (params) => params.api.getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows(params.id),
}]
rows={[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]}
/>`

Thanks, I edited the question text. I use DataGridPremium component

But this code still doesn’t work when I sort/filter column in the table (((


export default function DataTable() {
  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'rowNumber',
      headerName: 'Row Number',
      width: 100,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return <>{params.rowIndex + 1}</>;
      },
    },
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 130 }
  ];

  const rows = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}   
      />
    </div>
  );
}




I use latest version of @mui/x-data-grid-premium 7.3.0  but rowIndex does not exist on type of cell params in renderCell
